# How can I find files that only have certain permission for owner?

Tags: linux, bash, file, permissions, find

I would like to find files only by a certain user's permission.
For example, if I want to find a file that I have full permission.

I may do something like:

```
find . -user $(whoami) -perm
```

But what should I put after `-perm` if I want to ignore the permission of root and other users.

Comment: `man find`: `-perm u+rwx`

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Start with:

```
find /path/to/file -user user1 -perm -u+rwx
```

This means: look for files starting in `/path/to/files`, owned by `user1`, where the permissions for group and other can be anything (`-` in front of the permission string) and the users permissions are only: `rwx`

To search for files only (no directories) then add `-type f`.

Also, try some reading. This has great examples: [Find tutorial](http://www.softpanorama.org/Tools/Find/index.shtml)

Comment: Thanks it worked. I would like to vote for your answer, but I don't have enough reputation. :)

Answer (score 25):

From [the *manpages* of `find`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find):

> `-perm -mode`
>
> All of the permission bits `mode` are set for the file. Symbolic modes are accepted in this form, and this is usually the way in which would want to use them. You must specify 'u', 'g' or 'o' if you use a symbolic mode.

And so:

```
find . -user $(whoami) -perm -007
```

for the specified user, it returns files with the following privileges: *rwx*,

```
find . -user $(whoami) -perm -006
```

for the specified user, it returns files with the following privileges: *rwx*, *rw*,

```
find . -user $(whoami) -perm -005
```

for the specified user, it returns files with the following privileges: *rwx*, *rx*,

```
find . -user $(whoami) -perm -004
```

for the specified user, it returns files with the following privileges: *rwx*, *rw*, *rx*, *r*,

```
find . -user $(whoami) -perm -003
```

for the specified user, it returns files with the following privileges: *rwx*, *wx*,

```
find . -user $(whoami) -perm -002
```

for the specified user, it returns files with the following privileges: *rwx*, *rw*, *wx*, *w*,

```
find . -user $(whoami) -perm -001
```

for the specified user, it returns files with the following privileges: *rwx*, *rx*, *wx*, *x*,

```
find . -user $(whoami) -perm -000
```

for the specified user, it returns files with the following privileges: *rwx*, *rw*, *rx*, *wx*, *r*, *w*, *x*, *0*,

> `-perm /mode`
>
> Any of the permission bits `mode` are set for the file. Symbolic modes are accepted in this form. You must specify 'u', 'g' or 'o' if you use a symbolic mode. (...) If no permission bits in mode are set, this test matches any file (the idea here is to be consistent with the behaviour of `-perm -000`).

Examples:

```
find . -user $(whoami) -perm /007
```

for the specified user, it returns files with the following privileges: *rwx*, *rw*, *rx*, *wx*, *r*, *w*, *x*,

```
find . -user $(whoami) -perm /006
```

for the specified user, it returns files with the following privileges: *rwx*, *rw*, *rx*, *wx*, *r*, *w*,

```
find . -user $(whoami) -perm /005
```

for the specified user, it returns files with the following privileges: *rwx*, *rw*, *rx*, *wx*, *r*, *x*,

```
find . -user $(whoami) -perm /004
```

for the specified user, it returns files with the following privileges: *rwx*, *rw*, *rx*, *r*,

```
find . -user $(whoami) -perm /003
```

for the specified user, it returns files with the following privileges: *rwx*, *rw*, *rx*, *wx*, *w*, *x*,

```
find . -user $(whoami) -perm /002
```

for the specified user, it returns files with the following privileges: *rwx*, *rw*, *wx*, *w*,

```
find . -user $(whoami) -perm /001
```

for the specified user, it returns files with the following privileges: *rwx*, *rx*, *wx*, *x*,

```
find . -user $(whoami) -perm /000
```

for the specified user, it returns files with the following privileges: *rwx*, *rx*, *rw*, *wx*, *r*, *w*, *x*, *0*.

Examples have been tested.