# Bash find file with specific permission for group, no matter permission for user and others

Tags: bash, find

Using only octal notation, I need to find file that have only read permissions for group, no matter which owner and other permission are.

Which is the right command? 
I cant find it.

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how can I find files that only has the certain permission for owner using bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15247563/how-can-i-find-files-that-only-has-the-certain-permission-for-owner-using-bash)

Comment: take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15247563/how-can-i-find-files-that-only-has-the-certain-permission-for-owner-using-bash).

Comment: I saw that post but there is no reference to octal notation using -perm.
I am interested in checking Only specific group permission in octal notation.
In particular I have to check file that have only read permission for group. I don't mind the value of other permissions.

Answer (score 1):

To search for only files that have a particular bit set without regard to the rest of the bits you use the `-perm /<bits>` notation like

```
find -perm /040
```

to find all the files that have group read set

From the man page:

> -perm /mode
>         Any of the permission bits mode are set for the file.   Symbolic
>         modes  are  accepted in this form.  You must specify 'u', 'g' or
>         'o' if you use a symbolic mode.  See the  EXAMPLES  section  for
>         some  illustrative  examples.  If no permission bits in mode are
>         set, this test matches any file (the idea here is to be  consis‐
>         tent with the behaviour of -perm -000).